# Cross-compiling GLib for Windows is throwing an error "'XDG_MIME_TYPE_UNKNOWN' undeclared"

Tags: cross-compiling, glib, undeclared-identifier

While cross-compiling [GLib 2.32.4](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/glib2.html) with Mingw-w64 for Win32, I ran into the following error:

```
gcontenttype.c: In function 'g_content_type_guess':
gcontenttype.c:335:3: error: 'XDG_MIME_TYPE_UNKNOWN' undeclared (first use in this function)
gcontenttype.c:335:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

I can only assume one of two things:

- I am missing some sort of preprocessor definition or `./configure` flag (currently I only pass `--host` and `--prefix` to `./configure`).
- There is an error in the source code.

Some further digging around revealed that `XDG_MIME_TYPE_UNKNOWN` is defined `gio/xdgmime/xdgmime.h` like so:

```
extern const char xdg_mime_type_unknown[];
#define XDG_MIME_TYPE_UNKNOWN xdg_mime_type_unknown
```

This file doesn't seem to be included anywhere in `gcontenttype.c` however.

Is this a problem with the way I am compiling the library or is it a bug with the library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally just fixed up the source code myself.

`gcontenttype.c`:335

```
g_return_val_if_fail (data_size != (gsize) -1,
                      g_strdup (XDG_MIME_TYPE_UNKNOWN));
```

...becomes...

```
g_return_val_if_fail (data_size != (gsize) -1,
                      g_strdup ("application/octet-stream"));
```

The library now compiles without error.

Comment: You might want to send a patch to upstream

Comment: Thank you for being altruist, first Hit on Google. Saved me time !

Comment: @bratao: You're welcome! I'm glad to know that all of the frustration I went through was helpful to somebody :)